# Regular expression to remove empty tags except one

Tags: javascript, regex

Can anyone help me with a javascript regular expression that remove all empty tags except script tags, except the script tag `<script src="myjs.js"></script>`.

I have tried the following expression and it removes all the tags including script tags.

```
var regex = new RegExp(/<([^\s>]+)[^>]*>\s*<\/\1>/gi);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that (based on [this answer [ru]](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/433441/178988))

```
html
  .replace(/<!--[\s\S]*?--!?>/g, "")
  .replace(/<(?!script)([a-z]+)[^>]*(>\s*<\/\1>|\s*$)/gi, "")
```

Comment: @Charu, if this code solved your problem, accept an answer by clicking a checkmark near it.